# Delphi datatsource autoedit, which event

Tags: delphi, events, dataset, datasource

I have a datasource and a dataset in Delphi 2009. I would like, if my a column (AT) value = 1, then datasource autoedit properties will be true, other value false. I tried use onStateChange, but its not good event for me. This column have 2 value 1 or 0, and I saw, this if is true, but i dont know, which event can help me. :)
Example:

```
procedure TdmodUnion.dsoQuotationsStateChange(Sender: TObject); 
begin
if dsetQ.FieldByName('AT').AsInteger=1 then 
    dsourceQ.AutoEdit:=true; 
end;
```

What can i choose?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use OnDataChange, Field is within Parameters.
If you are using ADO, then AfterScrollEvent of then dataset is usefull, too.

Comment: procedure TdmodUnion.dsoQuotationsStateChange(Sender: TObject); begin if dsetQuotations.FieldByName('QType').AsInteger=0 then dsoQuotations.DataSet.Cancel; end;

Thanks answer,but i could search a solution with onStateChange.

Comment: I dislike your AfterScroll event advise, since the DataSource may (and should) be unknown to the module where the DataSet resides.